# Understanding why this natural log formula rewrite works

Tags: logarithms

I came across this question in my homework and am unsure why it works this way.

Given $y= \ln(e^{x^2})$, find the derivative.

The given answer work showed the formula rewritten as $y=x^{2}$ before starting the differentiation process.  My thinking is because

$$f(x)=\ln(x)$$

And the inverse of the natural log function is
$$ f^{-1}(x)=e^x$$

Am I right in thinking that multiplying the inverses cancel each other out?  If so, why doesn't the x be removed, leaving the 2 as a constant?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by the last sentence.

Comment: You seem to be confused with the (admittedly) confusing use of the term "inverse" in mathematics; inverse here means that $\ln(e^x)=x$, not $e^x\ln\,x=1$. You can do the simplification suggested, or use the chain rule if you've the discipline.

Comment: @ J.M: You should put that as an answer.  I actually had that written down in my notes, but it was surrounded with other descriptions and I missed it.  Thanks!  @Quaochu Yuan, JM hit my confusion on the head, check his comment.

Comment: Why do you keep saying "cancel"? $\ln$ "undoes" what the exponential function does to a number (that precisely is the meaning of "inverse" here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are right that $x\mapsto\ln(x)$ and $x\mapsto e^x$ are inverse functions for each other.  This is the most important thing here.  For real $x$ we have $\ln(e^x)=x$ and for real $x>0$ we have $e^{\ln(x)}=x$. (since $\ln(x)$ is not defined when $x\leq 0$)

But there is no reason for the $x$ to go away.  I'll write it another way:  No matter what the box $\square$ is, in the real case we will always have  $$\ln (e^{\square})=\square.$$   So for your problem, imagine that $\square=x^2$.  Then we must have $$\ln (e^{x^2})=x^2.$$  Lets do more examples:

$$\ln (e^{\sin(x)})=\sin (x)$$

$$\ln(e^{f(x)})=f(x).$$

I hope that helps explain it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Eric: I know you know the meaning of what you write but, considering the discussion in the comments about the word *inverse*, I would suggest replacing the first sentence of your post by something like *the* **functions** *$x\mapsto\ln(x)$ and $x\mapsto\mathrm{e}^x$ are inverse of each other*.

Answer (score 4):

Beware of the unmodified word inverse. The natural log and the exponential functions are *compositional* inverses of one another.  The numbers 2 and 1/2 are *multiplicative* inverses.  Do not confuse these.

Comment: That clarification helps because I was under the impression that natural log and exponential functions were also multiplicative inverses.